# Can't attach statically provisioned EBS volume to EKS node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

I've configured my EKS setup to support EBS by following the docs [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver). I've verified that this works by successfully deploying [dynamically provisioned](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/dynamic-provisioning) EBS volumes. I'm now trying to use [static provisioning](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/static-provisioning) and I'm failing.

My volume is ready to attach in the AWS console:

[image]

I've verified that the PV and PVC for the new statically provisioned volume are ok (`firehose-mainnet-test-volume` points to the `vol-0a493db74622155d0` from the screenshot above)

```
 ❯❯❯ k get pv
k get pvc
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                               STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume        1000Gi     RWO            Retain           Bound    default/firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume-claim   io2                     103m
mercury-ipfs-ipfs-efs-pv                   20Gi       RWX            Retain           Bound    default/mercury-ipfs-ipfs-efs-pvc                   efs-sc                  362d
pvc-e823a3b9-94be-449e-8248-ef1a023d8cc9   2000Gi     RWO            Delete           Bound    default/firehose-mainnet-reader-ebs-pvc             gp2-ebs-sc              40d
 9:27AM /Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/firehose/go-ethereum tags/geth-v1.10.25-fh2 ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ k get pvc
NAME                                        STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
firehose-mainnet-reader-ebs-pvc             Bound    pvc-e823a3b9-94be-449e-8248-ef1a023d8cc9   2000Gi     RWO            gp2-ebs-sc     40d
firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume-claim   Bound    firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume        1000Gi     RWO            io2            81m
mercury-ipfs-ipfs-efs-pvc                   Bound    mercury-ipfs-ipfs-efs-pv                   20Gi       RWX            efs-sc         362d
```

This volume fails to mount when describing my pod:

```
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  2m44s                  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-e823a3b9-94be-449e-8248-ef1a023d8cc9"
  Warning  FailedMount             45s                    kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume-claim], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-smcss jwt firehose-mainnet-reader-ebs-pvc firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume-claim]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume      20s                    attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "firehose-mainnet-reader-test-volume" : Attach timeout for volume vol-0a493db74622155d0
```

When I look at the logs for the `ebs-csi-controller` I see the following output:

```
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 csi-attacher I1212 12:43:38.294065       1 csi_handler.go:248] Attaching "csi-f61a123c75ba67f92a9482f96ca3fa133d9f4f6af9bc924c545f08a05da4a85e"
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 ebs-plugin E1212 12:43:38.651776       1 driver.go:120] GRPC error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-0a493db74622155d0" to node "i-0f994790a01e365d2": could not attach volume "vol-0a493db74622155d0" to node "i-0f994790a01e365d2": UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: 86wH2-qNGBPhlKSt0fyV9CfjiZCvdgoQmTX7EmWlB9Dwmj8VjAWo7VaLEobbh4lNuLM0bmCnWOPgntBaRP2jwqap6koIsjikjt4Takcv49FZZ0SmO4GLhqpzBx88k1YAUE3n0DJp_ip6gW-oVvb2FD16tOfU5iJn6dyCUUzGlguhPn20WbzZuYitvpfXlK4m2RSiQDZPDHOesmsDWREN5d-p086kAQAUdLauoNaTd-qDWf497Yh5pwR4WXYM3hWi8SxSSs7y6sQ8idTjj8GHUjJOrsZC_hRCMO-NhOMy-agBwT4gYziOzaZ-AVxlhv7YW27Yd-azNrumAuA4JykN8YtE76h1RFJ16SuIFBrhx4mEsMR-pjuLLnuTbk6hdkXqeoPE9xoIx6pL12HwiblTDOQo8nM2utNK_p0ZYefb1IlJuIjm8CrgbmxyXu5wZWcsZKOnufdTh6G2Hj46kT0OHDI7-NJbyu4d8NkQ5LvQvX_wHVc2JAonNsRj5VuQZZr6G5C1FJrNiu44-LnhWB92LMR9ho7maHegKKrQ-DLy9UHuVS9fq5xNdyEgYAaNFGn8MkJxsSplFUQm25HByt39hCbeuwoYkUHtpite9ufqoMvTElYJBDFkasVec2RxhnYcPuyQ7pPj26IcUquW5wKD
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 csi-attacher I1212 12:43:38.660565       1 csi_handler.go:255] Failed to save attach error to "csi-f61a123c75ba67f92a9482f96ca3fa133d9f4f6af9bc924c545f08a05da4a85e": VolumeAttachment.storage.k8s.io "csi-f61a123c75ba67f92a9482f96ca3fa133d9f4f6af9bc924c545f08a05da4a85e" is invalid: status.attachError.message: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 ebs-plugin  status code: 403, request id: c1eeb49c-955f-4969-9fcd-1a83933de338
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 csi-attacher I1212 12:43:38.660604       1 csi_handler.go:231] Error processing "csi-f61a123c75ba67f92a9482f96ca3fa133d9f4f6af9bc924c545f08a05da4a85e": failed to attach: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-0a493db74622155d0" to node "i-0f994790a01e365d2": could not attach volume "vol-0a493db74622155d0" to node "i-0f994790a01e365d2": UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: 86wH2-qNGBPhlKSt0fyV9CfjiZCvdgoQmTX7EmWlB9Dwmj8VjAWo7VaLEobbh4lNuLM0bmCnWOPgntBaRP2jwqap6koIsjikjt4Takcv49FZZ0SmO4GLhqpzBx88k1YAUE3n0DJp_ip6gW-oVvb2FD16tOfU5iJn6dyCUUzGlguhPn20WbzZuYitvpfXlK4m2RSiQDZPDHOesmsDWREN5d-p086kAQAUdLauoNaTd-qDWf497Yh5pwR4WXYM3hWi8SxSSs7y6sQ8idTjj8GHUjJOrsZC_hRCMO-NhOMy-agBwT4gYziOzaZ-AVxlhv7YW27Yd-azNrumAuA4JykN8YtE76h1RFJ16SuIFBrhx4mEsMR-pjuLLnuTbk6hdkXqeoPE9xoIx6pL12HwiblTDOQo8nM2utNK_p0ZYefb1IlJuIjm8CrgbmxyXu5wZWcsZKOnufdTh6G2Hj46kT0OHDI7-NJbyu4d8NkQ5LvQvX_wHVc2JAonNsRj5VuQZZr6G5C1FJrNiu44-LnhWB92LMR9ho7maHegKKrQ-DLy9UHuVS9fq5xNdyEgYAaNFGn8MkJxsSplFUQm25HByt39hCbeuwoYkUHtpite9ufqoMvTElYJBDFkasVec2RxhnYcPuyQ7pPj26IcUquW5wKD
ebs-csi-controller-7485b8586d-jwng9 csi-attacher        status code: 403, request id: c1eeb49c-955f-4969-9fcd-1a83933de338
```

How can I attach a statically generated ebs volume to my node? I've verified that the node and volume are both in the same region, `us-west-2c`. Is there anything else I need to check to ensure that the volume can be mounted to the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the service account for my ebs csi controller didn't have an `assumeRole` annotation. Adding that fixed the issue.

```
kubectl annotate serviceaccount ebs-csi-controller-sa \
    -n kube-system \
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn=arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem similar to this. I was trying to mount a new volume that was created from a snapshot of an existing volume. The PV/PVC were created without issue, but the pod would time out when trying to mount the volume.

I checked the ebs-csi-controller logs and found it was getting a 403 error when trying to attach the volume. It turns out the IAM policy used by the service account for ebs-csi-controller had a condition that to mount a volume it needed a tag of "KubernetesCluster: my-cluster-name".

I added the missing tag to the volume in AWS and then the ebs-csi-controller could mount the volume properly and my pod started up.